# How to convert Graphics into Image or Bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap

How to convert Graphics into Image or Bitmap?

I have this code and it successfully crops my image in a picturebox but when I try to save it into a database.. it's empty.

```
Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(pctImage.Image, pctImage.Width, pctImage.Height);
Graphics g = frmAdd.pctImage.CreateGraphics();

Rectangle rectCropArea;
rectCropArea = new Rectangle(50, 3, 230, 240);

g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, frmAdd.pctImage.Width, frmAdd.pctImage.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
sourceBitmap.Dispose();
```

What should I do with this one? Thanks.

Comment: You're not showing your code how you're trying to save it to a database.

Comment: Don't dispose the bitmap right after creating it.  Save it first, *then* dispose it.  That comes natural when you use the *using* statement.

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100,100,graphics);
```

Comment: No. Read the docs - that doesn't copy the pixels into the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Use a structure like this:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
               //draw image..
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: Returning a disposed bitmap is a Really Bad Idea.

Comment: Per Hans comment, the correct way to do this is to put *all* code using `bitmap` inside the `using .. bitmap`.  So for the question asked, that means doing  `save` where it now says `return bitmap`. (And *do not* return that bitmap, as it is disposed when the `using` context ends.)